# javascript selector with outerheight function isn't returning anything, and I can't select the selector anywhere else either

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to debug this in chrome dev tools but the variables for topMenuHeight and scrollItems are just always null or with length 0 so empty. One variable is literally just $(selector).outerheight() and it is returning null. I know for absolute sure that the html ul has the proper ID, anyway, here's all the codee

So we've got the nav:

```
 <nav>
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="#splash"><i style="padding-right: 5px;" class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a><div></div></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Ordering</a><div></div></li>
        <li><a href="#designs" target="_blank">Designs</a><div></div></li>
        <li><a href="#hotels-resorts" target="_blank">Hotels / Resorts</a><div></div></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

and some js

```
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#navmenu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });
```

and

```
var navHeight = $("#navmenu").outerHeight(true) ;

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+navHeight;
```

I really can't figure it out, I'm pretty good at python but from what I can tell this selector should be working........

Comment: Did you put the script before the HTML without a `document.ready` ?

Comment: It should work fine, maybe it's a syntax error, but probably you just missed `document.ready`. https://jsfiddle.net/55844nne/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked and debugged your website.
You should use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //place your js here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi when i checked your Website you include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu-scroll.js"></script>
```

before creating the elemnet $("#navmenu")

so its intially empty so this

```
var navHeight = $("#navmenu").outerHeight(true) ;
```

become null

wither u include the script aftr the navmenu or add the document ready inside the menu scroll

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //place your js here
})
```

;